# MVC'ify WebForms Control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-controls

Currently, I am passing data from my codebehind into hidden fields like so:

Code behind: `HiddenField statusValue.Value = progressPercent.ToString();`

.ASCX page: `<asp:HiddenField ID="statusValue" value="" runat="server" />`

In MVC, I would pass a model from my controller to a view.  Is there a similar way to do this in webforms?  I am beginning to have a large number of hidden fields and it seems like a bad way to program this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, having tons of hidden fields isn't the best practice. Have you looked into ASP.NET View State? It may achieve what you are looking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Would you liken WebForm's ViewState to MVC's ViewBag or ViewData?

Comment: I'm guessing it's more like MVC's View Bag. I haven't done a direct comparison between each one.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron.  I have heard bad things about ViewState's complexity; but I will try it out.

Comment: Be sure to read up on the second link as it describes the ASP.NET page life cycle and where the View State fits in.

Comment: ViewState is not complex at all. Just use it wisely when you dont need it turn it off its not a bad thing.

Comment: I appears I can simply access variables in my .ascx directly from my .cs page!  Is there anything wrong with doing just this and avoiding viewstate all together?

Comment: You can include the variable on the .ascx side if you want. It just depends on how you want to abstract your business logic/view layers.